# Async Http Client + Netty

Tags: java, netty, asynchttpclient

I am facing issues benchmarking the async http client (version - 2.4.3) and getting the following exception while running the code pasted below. Also just FYI I am new to Netty as well as async-http-client so pardon me in case I have gap in my understanding.

```
exception - io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
```

The following are my assumptions -

- The below code will have a single thread (single eventloop).
- keepalive will ensure that tcp connections are reused
- The size of the tcp connections is determined by setMaxConnections &
  setMaxConnectionsPerHost
- ThrottleRequestFilter will ensure that request will not be made when all
  connections are actively used by threads processing the handler code.

The following is my question -

1] Although I am using ThrottleRequestFilter why should I be seeing a connect timeout. My assumption is once the response is processed by the handler the connection should be available for reuse as I have the keepalive set, unless I am missing on something.

2] What is the size of the default thread pool which executes the AsyncHandler code.

The following is my test run

```
Total Requests - N = 1000
Max Con = 1000
Max Con/Host = 1000
pcit = 60000
ka = true
```

and the following are the metrics -

```
======================================
Total num of Reqs:  1000
Concurrency :   1000
Total Time in secs: 1.0
HTTP 200 OK:    789
HTTP 200 NOT OK:    211
Total Completed :   1000
rps : 789.0
======================================

public class HttpBm {

final Metrics metrics;
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

public HttpBm(Metrics metrics) {
    this.metrics = metrics;
}

private void run(int n, int mc, int mcph, int pcit, boolean ka, String url) {

    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = Dsl.asyncHttpClient(Dsl.config()
            .addRequestFilter(new ThrottleRequestFilter(mcph))
            .setMaxConnections(mc)
            .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(mcph)
            .setKeepAlive(ka)
            .setConnectTimeout(1000)
            .setConnectionTtl(500));

    for (int r=0;r<n;r++) {

        final ListenableFuture<Response> whenResponse = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).execute(new AsyncHandler<Response>() {

            private Integer status;

            public State onStatusReceived(HttpResponseStatus responseStatus) throws Exception {
                if (200 == responseStatus.getStatusCode())
                    metrics.incrHttp200OK();
                else
                    metrics.incrHttpNon200OK();
                return State.ABORT;
            }

            public State onHeadersReceived(HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
                return State.ABORT;
            }

            public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) throws Exception {
                return State.ABORT;
            }

            public void onThrowable(Throwable t) {
                metrics.incrHttpNon200OK();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            public Response onCompleted() throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    boolean done = true;

    while (done) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        done = metrics.print(startTime, endTime);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 1000;
    int mc = 1000;
    int mcph = 1000;
    int pcit = 60000;
    String url = "http://somehost:8080/index.html";

    if (args != null) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        mc = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        mcph = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        pcit = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        url = args[4];
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("==================================");
    System.out.println("Url = " + url);
    System.out.println("Total Requests - N = " + n);
    System.out.println("Max Con = " + mc);
    System.out.println("Max Con/Host = " + mcph);
    System.out.println("pcit = " + pcit);
    System.out.println("ka = true");

    System.out.println("==================================");

    HttpBm httpBm = new HttpBm(new Metrics(n, mc));

    httpBm.run(n , mc, mcph, pcit, true, url);
}
```

}

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Metrics {

private int n;
private int c;

private AtomicInteger Http200OK = new AtomicInteger();
private AtomicInteger HttpNon200OK = new AtomicInteger();

public Metrics(int n, int c) {
    this.n = n;
    this.c = c;
}

public void incrHttp200OK() {
    Http200OK.incrementAndGet();
}

public void incrHttpNon200OK() {
    HttpNon200OK.incrementAndGet();
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return Http200OK.get() + HttpNon200OK.get() >= n;
}

public boolean print(long startTime, long finishTime) {

    final float totalTimeSec = (finishTime - startTime) / 1000000000;
    final float rps = this.Http200OK.get() / totalTimeSec;

    System.out.println("======================================");
    System.out.println("Total num of Reqs:\t" + n);
    System.out.println("Concurrency :\t" + c);
    System.out.println("Total Time in secs:\t" +  totalTimeSec);
    System.out.println("HTTP 200 OK:\t" +  Http200OK.get());
    System.out.println("HTTP 200 NOT OK:\t" + HttpNon200OK.get());
    System.out.println("Total Completed :\t" + (Http200OK.get() + HttpNon200OK.get()));
    System.out.println("rps : " + rps);
    System.out.println("======================================");

    return isComplete();
}
```

}

Comment: I figured it out. I was setting the io and response threads inappropriately.